# Grep string and remove 1st character

Tags: sed, awk, grep, tr

I want to remove 1st character on file when grep some string. But need that changed row to be on the same position before the edit.

Example file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
auth            include         system-auth
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

Expected View after the edit:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
auth            include         system-auth
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

In that case on 4th row need just to remove "#", but I want to do that when search the string "sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid" not when point the exact row that I want to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^#(.*sufficient\s+pam_wheel\.so trust use_uid.*)/\1/' file
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
auth            include         system-auth
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

Regexplanation:

```
s/                            # Substitute  
^#                            # A line starting with a #
(                             # Start capture group
.*                            # Followed by anything
sufficient                    # Followed by the word sufficient
\s+                           # Followed by whitespace
pam_wheel\.so trust use_uid   # Followed by the literal string (escaped .)
.*                            # Followed by anything
)                             # Stop capture group
/                             # Replace with 
\1                            # The first capture group
```

So effectively we are matching lines starting with `#` containing the string `sufficient\s+pam_wheel.so trust use_uid` and removing the `#`

Notes: the `-r` flag is for extended regexp, it might be `-E` for your version of `sed` so check the `man`.

If you want to store the changes back to the `file` use the `-i` option:

```
$ sed -ri 's/^#(.*sufficient\s+pam_wheel\.so trust use_uid.*)/\1/' file
```

If the column aligment is important then capture up to `sufficient` and after it so you get 2 capture groups and replace with `\1 \2`.

```
$ sed -r 's/^#(.*)(sufficient\s+pam_wheel\.so trust use_uid.*)/\1 \2/' file
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth            sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
auth            include         system-auth
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

**Edit:**

Replace the string `AllowUsers support admin` with `#AllowUsers support admin`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(AllowUsers support admin.*)/#\1/' file
#AllowUsers support admin

$ sed -r 's/^(DeniedUsers root.*)/#\1/' file
#DeniedUsers root
```

Comment: Another case if I have file with:

    `AllowUsers      support admin`

How to make that file to be:

    `#AllowUsers      support admin`
     `DeniedUsers     root`

Comment: actually 
DeniedUsers root
is on a new line and may be is good to replace whole row which contain AllowUsers

Comment: Well I find solution for my self:
`sed -r 's/(AllowUsers.*)/#\1 \nDeniedUsers root/'`

Thanks, @sudo_O

Comment: Now I understand from seeing your code, yes that is what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e '$_=~s/^.//g if(/sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid/)' your_file
```

Note: This would do inplace replacement.so after you run the command your file will be modified automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F '#' '{ if ($0 ~ /^#.*sufficient +pam_wheel.so trust use_uid/) {$1=""; print;} else print}'  infile
```

OR (if there can be only one # at the start):

```
awk -F '#' '{ if ($0 ~ /^#.*sufficient +pam_wheel.so trust use_uid/) print $2; else print}'  infile
```

Comment: Quote `but I want to do that when search the string "sufficient pam_wheel.so trust use_uid" not when point the exact row that I want to edit`

Comment: @sudo_O: Thanks for pointing this though it can still be done in a simple awk command. Pls check the edited answer now.

Comment: Better but you are only printing the matching line without the `#` not very useful without print all the lines in the file.

Comment: Good, it should be pointed out that using `awk` requires redirection to make the changes to the file `awk '{...}' file > new_file` or `awk '{...}' file > tmp; mv tmp file`

Comment: Yes true awk doesn't have `sed -i` like feature.

Comment: The above would fail to reproduce the whole target line if "#" could appear anywhere else on the line, e.g. `#foo bar # this is the foo line`, or would introduce a blank at the start of the line.

Comment: @EdMorton: `^#.*` can be easily replaced with `^ *#.*` for that

Comment: @anubhava My comment wasn't about lines that start with spaces, it was about lines that start with # and contain other #s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed '/sufficient \+pam_wheel.so \+trust \+use_uid/s/^#//' file
```

Results:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
auth            include         system-auth
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

sed commands can only do RE matches not string comparisons so to use sed you'd need to parse your desired string to escape all RE metacharacters which is error-prone (e.g. the currently posted solutions all neglect to escape the "." in `pam_wheel.so`).

Better to just do a string comparison when you're trying to match a string, e.g.:

```
awk 'index($0,"sufficient pam_wheel.so trust use_uid"){sub/^#/,"")}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```